# Where does xcode 4 get the user name for file templates

Tags: xcode, xcode4

When I create a new file in xcode, the file template emits the following line:

```
//  Created by ANONYMOUS ANONYMOUS on 11/2/11.
```

According to the docs, this should be using the full user name of the currently logged in user, but it's substituting ANONYMOUS ANONYMOUS instead.  Anyone know why it's not using my user name?  The variable it's substituting for is `___FULLUSERNAME___`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it pulls information for the "me" card in your AddressBook to replace the `___FULLUSERNAME___` and `__MyCompanyName__` values. (In AddressBook.app "Card" menu, select "Go to My Card" and see if you have any data entered. You can set any card in your address book to be your "me" card and the basis for those values.)

I've also seen developers use the `defaults` command line tool to set those values explicitly rather than using the variables above when they wanted to swap details without changing their address book identity. For example when writing code on behalf of multiple companies.

> > defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions '{"ORGANIZATIONNAME" = "My organization";}'

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005535-CH3-SW10

Comment: This is correct, it comes from your computers address book entry for the current user.

Comment: Wow, that is super annoying that it gets it from the address book. I very purposely don't keep accurate information in the "My Card" entry of the address book for security/privacy reasons.  Why can't they just get that information from my logged in user? Apple. Apple. Apple.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the value of `FULLUSERNAME` in `PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions` doesn't affect the name that appears in the template.